C# Azure Functions in Isolated Worker Model with Manual Trigger
It was once the case (in the previous in-process model of Azure Functions), that one could decorate a function that had no input bindings with a [NoAutomaticTrigger] attribute, and then invoke the function either via through Azure Portal or the Function App's HTTP management interface (not to be confused with a HTTP input binding).
I'm moving some code over to .NET 8 using the isolated worker model functions and can't seem to find the equivalent of the [NoAutomaticTrigger] - does anybody know if this functionality is still available, and if so how it can be achieved?

James, did I answer your question? If so, can you please accept it?

@VladDX not really. The question was "does this functionality still exist?", which I don't think you addressed, and instead provided a workaround, which while appreciated, I'd already considered.

It believe, it doesn't exist anymore.

I'm curious, what would you expect as the right answer when there no such a thing anymore? What's the original problem you are trying to solve with [NoAutomaticTrigger]? Why do you need it?

You can call non-HTTP triggers via HTTP.
For example, you can use an HTTP call to run a TimerTrigger, QueueTrigger, ServiceBusTrigger, and so on.
You can even run a disabled HTTP trigger using the same technique.

To call any function via HTTP simply make a POST call to the URL:
https://<FUNCTION-APP-NAME>.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/<FUNCTION-NAME>


Therefore, from my perspective there are two main options:

Just create an HTTP trigger with either function or admin Authorization level.
Nobody else but a holder of the key (you) would be able to call it.

Create an HTTP trigger and disable it by following the documentation: How to disable functions in Azure Functions
You still will be able to call it using the technique to manually run a non HTTP-triggered function. It is going to work with a master key.

Microsoft Learn: Azure / Functions / Manually run a non HTTP-triggered function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-manually-run-non-http?tabs=azure-cli



